# Where is the screwdriver in The Walking Dead: Episode 2?

Tags: the-walking-dead-season-one

Hit a brick wall at the dairy farm. Without spoiling anything, I'm told that I need a screwdriver, but I can find any tools besides the multitool. How do I progress the story?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The multitool is the screwdriver.** If you're told that you need the screwdriver for the generator, return to the generator and use the multitool action ("←") instead of the hand action ("↓").

Answer (score 0):

There is a table near the generator. On that table is a toolbox. In that toolbox is a Multi-tool, that can also be used as a screwdriver.

Answer (score 0):

Go out of the barn to the toolbox on the table by the generator get the multitool: go to the panel on the generator, take the belt off, and go to the door in the barn.